Цвет спрайта в юнити
У меня на 2д сцене есть спрайт, допустим красный квадрат котрый я только что импортировал, теперь я хочу его покрасить в белый, пользуюсь компонентом SpriteRenderer и меняю параметр color на new Color32(255, 255, 255, 255). Тут и заключается проблема, квадрат так и останется красным, и так с наложением любого цвета, цвет будет не такой какой я задаю. Как найти выход из этой ситуации? Как сделать чтобы цвет задавался строго так как нужно и не искажался бы из-за исходного цвета спрайта при импорте?

Ну красный квадрат ты импортировал свой, цвет ты можешь поменять только у квадрата из предустановленных спрайтов (GameObject -> 2D -> Sprites -> Square)

Параметр Color это цвет на который перемножается цвет спрайт. С его помощью можно поменять тон и полупрозрачность он изначатьно Color(1, 1, 1, 1). А то что ты хочешь, это перекрытие (Tint Color) и таким, базовый шейдер для спрайта не занимается. Нужно просто сделать свой шейдер.

Как было сказано в комментариях, цвет спрайта перемножается на цвет, указанный в инспекторе. Поэтому из условно красного квадрата можно получить белый только написав свои собственные шейдеры
Но в данном случае можно поступить немного по-другому и импортировать белый квадрат. В таком случае, вы сможете задавать цвет в инспекторе, и квадрат будет окрашиваться в этот цвет. Но тут нужно быть осторожным с цветами обводок, потому что любой не чёрный цвет на спрайте тоже изменится в сторону заданного в инспекторе.
